# How to make a C platform communicate with a nodejs server?

Tags: c, node.js, freebsd

I'm searching for an efficient solution to make a C Freebsd platform communicate with a Node.js server.
Here are my requirements:

- the client must be able to send binary streams and text messages (typically JSON messages)
- those messages can be multiplexed: for instance, a text message can be sent while a binary stream is being sent.

I was heading to the [libwebsockets](https://libwebsockets.org/) library, but it seems to be a half-dead project, no multiplexing extension support, for instance.
I thought to implement a TCP/IP solution myself.

Comment: A server is a server. What does it matter how it's written? Just use any of 100 C libraries for talking with servers.

Comment: Writing a client is probably easier and faster in a language like Python or Ruby. Use C if other solutions aren't fast enough.